# if (cin >> x) - Why can you use that condition?

Tags: c++, variables, if-statement, cin

I have been using "Accelerated C++" to learn C++ over the summer, and there's a concept which I don't seem to understand properly.

Why is

```
int x;
if (cin >> x){}
```

equivalent to

```
cin >> x;
if (cin){}
```

By looking at the code, it seems to me that we're using cin as a variable. But, I thought it was a function. Why can we use cin in this way when it is x that has whatever value we input into our keyboard?

Answer (score 78):

`cin` is an object of class [`istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) that represents the standard input stream. It corresponds to the `cstdio` stream `stdin`. The operator `>>`overload for streams return a reference to the same stream. The stream itself can be evaluated in a boolean condition to true or false through a conversion operator.

`cin` provides formatted stream extraction. The operation
`cin >> x;`

where "x" is an int will fail if a non-numeric value is
entered. So:

```
if(cin>>x)
```

will return `false` if you enter a letter rather than a digit.

This website on [tips and tricks using C++ I/O](http://augustcouncil.com/~tgibson/tutorial/iotips.html) will help you too.

Comment: Sorry, that's too technical for me. I haven't gotten onto classes or anything like that. Why do we use boolean?

Comment: @Muhsin Ali: Trying to understand different things one stumbles across is generally good when learning something new. However in this case, I would recommend you to just regard `cin` and `cout` as "magic" for now. Of course they are not magic, but they are built using a number of quite advanced techniques. It is probably better to go on for now and then get back once you've mastered classes, inheritance and operator overloading.

Comment: @Muhsin: Because all that `if` accepts as the if expression is a boolean, an integer, or a pointer. The class `std::istream` provides the ability to convert an input stream to a boolean, and it is this conversion operator that is used in evaluating whether to perform the `if` branch or the `else` branch.

Comment: @Muhsin: If cin is presented with data it cannot process, it goes into a "fail state" so you have check it with an if statement. Go to the link I provided my last sentence. There is a code sample there.

Comment: @Muhsin :   `cin` is object of `istream` , which has overloaded operator >> for all built in types. see this like : `cin.operator>>(x);` , that is operator `>>` is nothing but member function of `cin`. For more clarification  read answer of David [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791520/if-cin-x-as-a-condition/6791854#6791854)

Comment: @David Hammen: Feeling in a very pedantic mood (its one of those mornings). It provides the ability to convert the stream into a type(unspecified) that can be used in a boolean context (boolExpr (ie anything that autoconverts to bool)). (Note: This has been changed to bool in the latest unreleased version C++0x (but is still not supported by most compilers)).

Comment: @DavidHammen *std::istream provides the ability to convert an input stream to a boolean, and it is this conversion operator that is used...* Could you please tell me about the conversion operator isteam provides?

Comment: @iamcreasy - I answered your question 2 years ago! See my answer below. Also note that my answer is for C++03. Things work a bit differently in C++11, but with the same end result of performing the then clause of the `if` statement if the stream extraction succeeds.

Comment: @DavidHammen Thanks. My bad, I missed it. Now it feels like a chain. One more question, what the difference between C++03 and C++11 in this context?

Comment: so `cin` returns value of `cin.good()`? What about something like `cin >> a >> b`? Is the value returned corresponds to the last input?

Answer (score 39):

Note: Answer updated four years after the fact to address both C++98/03 and C++11 (and beyond).

`std::cin` is an instance of a `std::istream`. That class provides two overloads that pertain to this question.

- `operator >>` reads data from the stream into the target variable if that is possible. If the immediate contents of the stream cannot be translated into the type of the target variable, the stream is instead marked as invalid and the target variable is left untouched. Regardless of the success/failure of the operation, the return value is a reference to the stream.
- Either `operator void*()` (pre-C++11), which converts the stream reference to a `void*` pointer, or `explicit operator bool()` (C++11), which converts the stream reference to a boolean. The result of this conversion is a non-null pointer (pre-C++11) or `true` (C++11) if the stream is valid, but the null pointer (pre-C++11) or `false` (C++11) if the stream isn't valid.

An `if` statement needs either a boolean, an integer, or a pointer as the quantity to be tested. The result of `std::cin >> x` is a reference to an `istream`, which is none of the above. However, the class `istream` does have those conversion operators which can be used to transform the `istream` reference to something usable in an `if` statement. It is the version-specific conversion operator that the language uses for the `if` test. Since failure to read marks the stream as invalid, the `if` test will fail if the read didn't work.

The reason for the more convoluted `operator void*` conversion member prior to C++11 is that it wasn't until C++11 that the already existing `explicit` keyword was extended to apply to conversion operators as well as constructors. A non-explicit `operator bool()` would have presented far too many opportunities for programmers to shoot themselves in the foot. There are problems with `operator void*()` as well. The "safe bool idiom" would have been a fix, but simply extending `explicit` accomplished exactly what the safe bool idiom accomplishes, and without having to use a lot of SFINAE magic.

Comment: It doesn't use `operator bool` but rather `operator void*`, operator bool would allow it to be used in arithmetical contexts whereas operator void* prevents this since void is an imcomplete type. In the implementation of the MSVC compiler operator void* returns the address of the object if no fail flag is set (which can't be 0 and therefore it's evaluated as `true` in a boolean context) or 0 if any flag is set (evaluating to boolean false).

Comment: According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/ it is `operator void*()` for C++98 and `operator bool()` for C++11.

Comment: @DavidHammen `std::cout<<(std::cin>>x);` if this fails gives output `0` and if succeed gives output `0x486650` why then it not give `1`. Also I didn't get exactly what are you saying `It is the version-specific conversion operator that the language uses for the if test.`

Comment: @AbhishekMane `std::cout<<(std::cin>>x);` fails to compile with a modern compliant compiler unless you tell it to compile against the C++98 standard (e.g., `--std=c++98`). In all versions of the standard, the return value from `std::cin>>x` is a reference to the `std::cin` object, and there is no overload `std::basic_ostream operator>> (const std::basic_istream&)`. Pre-C++11, the compiler would use `std::basic_istream::operator void*()`. This returns the null pointer if the input failed, a non-null pointer if the input succeeded. That's why you're seeing `0` or `0x48650`. (continued)

Comment: The `void*` conversion operator was deleted in C++11, replaced with `explicit operator bool()`. The `explicit` tag (new in C++11) explicitly tells the compiler not to use that conversion in `std::cout<<(std::cin>>x)`. That expression should result in a compilation error in a compliant compiler that is compiling against the C++11, C++14, C++17, or C++20 versions of the standard.

Comment: @AbhishekMane In the case of `if (std::cin>>x)` one is implicitly asking for a conversion to a `bool`. This worked in a pre-C++11 environment because even though `std::istream` didn't have an `operator bool`, it did have `operator void*`, and a `void*` can easily be converted to a `bool`. This works in a C++11 and beyond environment without having to write `if (bool(std::cin>>x))` because this is one of the few places in C++11 and beyond where an expression that can be "contextually converted to bool" is allowed, even in the case of `explicit operator bool()`.

Comment: @DavidHammen first of all thanks. Now I understand. you said `void*` can easily be converted to a `bool` but How ? and 2nd one is *`'There are few places in C++11 and beyond where an expression that can be "contextually converted to bool" is allowed, even in the case of explicit operator bool()*'' can you mention some of these few places apart from loops.

Comment: I get answer for my 2nd Question https://stackoverflow.com/q/39995573/11862989 user made question-answer type. Now just answer 1st one please.

Comment: @AbhishekMane The implicit conversion of numbers and pointers to a `bool` in the context of `if (foo)` has been a part of C++ since day 1. If `foo` is a numeric type, `if (foo)` is equivalent to `if (foo != 0)`. If `foo` is a pointer type, `if (foo)` is equivalent to `if (foo != NULL)` (or better, if one is using C++11 or beyond, `if (foo != nullptr)`). A pointer-type converts to `false` if the pointer is null, `true` otherwise. Personally, I would rather see an explicit comparison to the null pointer in code I write or review, but at the same time I do realize that `if (foo)` is valid.

Comment: @DavidHammen Got it. Just Clear explanation. Thanks Man.

Comment: @DavidHammen *"Personally, I would rather see an explicit comparison to the null pointer in code I write or review, but at the same time I do realize that if (foo) is valid."* I didn't get this. Can you elaborate please.

Comment: @AbhishekMane I'm not a fan of the implicit conversion to`bool`. For example, assuming `foo` is a pointer type, I far prefer to see `if ((foo != nullptr) && foo->is_valid())` over `if (foo && foo->is_valid())`. But that's personal preference. Given a halfway decent compiler, the two statements are identical in terms of generated assembly code.

Answer (score 7):

`cin` is a (global) variable of type `istream`, not a function.

The `istream` class overrides the `>>` operator to perform input and return a reference to the object you called it on (`cin`).

Comment: It doesn't return object, it return reference to object. Isn't it?

Comment: @Olympian: No, it is an instantiation.

Comment: If cin is also a variable, then could I write: x >> cin ?

Comment: @Mushin: Only if such an overload of `>>` exists.

Comment: @0A0D http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/ istream& operator>>(...) - it's return reference.

Comment: @SLaks Sorry. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Mushin: Before you can understand your question, you need to learn about operator overloading.

Comment: @Muhsin :   cin is object of istream , which has overloaded operator >> for all built in types . see this like : cin.operator>>(x) , that is >> is nothing but member function of cin

Comment: @Olympian: It's still an instantiation.

Answer (score 7):

`cin` is variable in `std` namespace.

`operator>>` return reference to `cin`, because of it you can write: `cin >> a >> b`, instead of `cin >> a; cin >> b;`

Answer (score 6):

The answers above are informative. Here I just give an extra comment.

`std::cin` is an object of class `istream` and represents the *standard input stream* (i.e. the keyboard) which corresponds to `stdin` in C *stream*.

`cin >> x` would firstly read an int from the standard input stream and assignment it to `x`. After that return a self reference to `cin`. So the return value of function call `cin >> x` is still `cin`.

So from the point of *if condition*, `if(cin)` and `if(cin >> x)` resemble each other. The standard *IO Library* defines a function for the stream like this (depends on implementation):

```
explicit operator bool() const; // C++11
```

or

```
operator void*() const; //C++98, C++2003
```

From this two declarations, we know they **cast** the *stream type* directly or indirectly(through `void*` pinter to `bool` which is obvious) to `bool` type.

Within this two functions, they depends on some basic *IO steam* statuses(class fields) to determine whether return false or true (for `void*` case, it is `nullptr` or not).

`cin` is an instance of class `istream` which inherits the **casting-to-bool** function. So it works!

Answer (score 5):

because the result of the expression

```
cin >> x
```

evaluates to

```
cin
```

after the stream is read.

Comment: So that means I can call on cin and it will still have that value of x, until I overwrite it?

Comment: Nope, cin will always be an instance of istream. But the variable x will continue to hold its value so there would be no need to get it from the stream again anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`std::cin` is an instance of the `std::istream` class.

`cin >> x` is just calling a function on the `cin` object. You can call the function directly:

```
cin.operator >>(x);
```

To allow you to read multiple variables at once the `operator >>` function returns a reference to the stream it was called on. You can call:

```
cin >> x >> y;
```

or equivalently:

```
cin.operator >>(x).operator >>(y);
```

or:

```
std::istream& stream = cin.operator >>(x);
stream.operator >>(y);
```

The final part of the puzzle is that `std::istream` [is convertible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) to `bool`. The bool is
equivalent to calling `!fail()`.

So in the following code:

```
int x;
std::istream& stream = std::cin.operator >>(x);
bool readOK = !stream.fail();
if (readOK)
{
  std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

`bool readOK = !stream.fail();` can be reduced to just `bool readOK = stream;`.

You don't need a separate `bool` to store the stream state so can just do `if (stream)`.

Removing the temporary `stream` variable gives `if (std::cin.operator >>(x))`.

Using the operator directly gets us back to the original code:

```
int x;
if (std::cin >> x)
{
  std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

Comment: `std::cout<<(std::cin>>x);` if this fails gives output `0`  and if succeed gives output `0x486650` why then it not give `1` .

Comment: @AbhishekMane I'm not sure what you mean but you could always open a new question with more details. `std::cout<<(std::cin>>x);` doesn't compile for me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68849622/11862989 I asked question. please answer.
Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/6791854/11862989 in this answer he mentioned `It is the version-specific conversion operator that the language uses for the if test.` which I think related to my Question but I am not getting it.

Answer (score 1):

1) `cin` is an instance of `istream`, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/.

2) the `>>` operator of `istream`  will return its left operand, in this case it is `cin`, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/. This operator will set `failbit` on if no characters were extracted from the `cin`, in case the reader has finished `EOF` so there will be no more character to read.

3) As of the 2) above, when the condition is evaluated after the reading operation, `if (cin >> x)` should be like `if (cin)`, refer to this link http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/ you will see that, this `if` block will return:

- A null pointer if at least one of `failbit` or `badbit` is set. Some other value otherwise (for C++98 standard).
- The function returns false if at least one of these error flags is set, and true otherwise. (for C++11 standard)

Answer (score 0):

because cin is an object of class, read more on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/ .