# Why Does the selection of 0 end this while loop?

Tags: c++

With this code I am trying to build an array with integer values entered by the user. the variable "int selection" is an int, so if the value entered is an int, the while loop should keep going, but the value 0 seems to end it and I can't figure out why. Thank you for your help guys.

```
int main()
{
  //data to be entered
  int selection;

  //array size
  int const array_size = 100;

  //array
  int integers[array_size];

  //array index
  int index = 0;

  //prompt
  std::cout << "Enter integer ('x' to quit): " << std::endl;

  //get the data
  std::cin >> selection;

  //while data is int
  while (selection)
  {
    //put it in the array
    integers[index] = selection;

    //increment index
    index += 1;

    //get new data point
    std::cin >> selection;

  }

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: `0` is the equivalent to `false`.

Comment: because value `0` is convertible to _bool_ `false`. As value `!= 0` is convertible to _bool_ `true`.

Comment: Setting `selection` to 0 ends your loop because you told it so: `while (selection)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`false` is interpreted as `0` in C++. Similarly, `0` is interpreted as `false` .
Hence, when `selection` is `0`, the loop effectively becomes:

```
while ( false )
{
...
}
```

which does not run.

On the other hand, when `selection` is not `0`, C++ treats it as `true` and the loop will run.

EDIT:
If you want to loop while the input is an integer, try

```
while (std::cin >> selection)
{
...
}
```

Comment: I actually want to be able to take 0 in, How do I actually get this done. I don't need code, just a better way to think about it

Comment: Edited, please try :)

Comment: Thank you Ranald. Just to make sure I understand, the line      while (cin >> selection){} means while we can get selection that is an int do what is in the braces

Comment: Yeap, you can check it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791520/if-cin-x-why-can-you-use-that-condition

Comment: "`false` is interpreted as `0` in C++. `0` is interpreted as `false`". So, how does this infinite recursion end?

Comment: @AndreyT  doesn't `while (false)` not run in the first place?

Comment: @RanaldLam: Correct. He was trying to simplify matters by showing post-evaluation code, but ended up inadvertently confusing them.

Answer (score 2):

This code won't do what the comment says that it would do:

```
//while data is int
while (selection)
```

The data will always be an `int`, it's not possible to store anything else in an `int` variable.

What the code actually does is to loop while the value is non-zero.

Comment: Oh ok I see. How should I approach this then. I do not need code just a better way to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Because `0` in Boolean context is interpreted as `false`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the code stands now and it works. Thank you guys for all your help

```
int main()
{
  //data to be entered
  int selection;

  //array size
  int const array_size = 100;

  //array
  int integers[array_size];

  //array index
  int index = 0;

  //prompt
  std::cout << "Enter integer ('x' to quit): " << std::endl;

  //while data is int
  while (std::cin >> selection)
  {
    //put it in the array
    integers[index] = selection;

    //increment index
    index += 1;

  }

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Nope, this won't compile, because `std::din` does not exist.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think it is a typo error and he meant std::cin

Answer (score 0):

`while (selection)` doesn't stop when `selection` is no longer an `int`; `selection` is *always* an `int`.

`while (selection)` stops when `selection` is not equal to `0`.

You should instead test the result of the `>>` operation.