# How does cin evaluate to true when inside an if statement?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I thought that:

```
if (true) 
{execute this statement}
```

So how does `if (std::cin >> X)` execute as true when there is nothing "true" about it? I could understand if it was `if ( x <= y)` or `if ( y [operator] x )`, but what kind of logic is    "istream = true?".

Comment: if "accepts" a bool. therefore anything inside the ( ) will be casted to bool, through operator bool(); also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791520/if-cin-x-why-can-you-use-that-condition

Comment: A stream is "true-ish" if the last operation was successful.

Comment: The first question you need to ask yourself is what is the value of the expression `(std::cin >> X)`.

Comment: @Exceptyon so that means any iostream evaluates to true? or only cin? sorry for the noob question

Comment: @chaosfirebit should return true if the read was successful. therefore if there was something left to read and conversion could be performed. int x; cin>>x; will return false on input "test"

Comment: @Exceptyon Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer depends on the version of the standard C++ library:

- Prior to C++11 the conversion inside `if` relied on converting the stream to `void*` using `operator void*`
- Starting with C++11 the conversion relies on [`operator bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) of `std::istream`

Note that `std::cin >> X` is not only a statement, but also an expression. It returns `std::cin`. This behavior is required for "chained" input, e.g. `std::cin >> X >> Y >> Z`. The same behavior comes in handy when you place input inside an `if`: the resultant stream gets passed to `operator bool` or `operator void*`, so a boolean value gets fed to the conditional.

Comment: so the answer is the same as if the question was about `if (cin)`?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Right, that's another way to put it.

Answer (score 7):

`std::cin` is of type `std::basic_istream` which inherits from std::basic_ios, which has an operator : [std::basic_ios::operator bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) which is called when used in if statement.

Answer (score 5):

`if(x)` is equivalent to `if(bool(x))`

in this case `bool(x)` calls  `std::istream::operator bool(x)`

this will return:

> true if none of `failbit` or `badbit` is set.
>
> false otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

What is inside `if` condition will be evaluated to `bool`.

`if(cin >> X)` means that if condition is `true`, something was read to `X`; if condition is `false`, something else happened (e.g. stream ended) and `X` is not changed.

E.g. to read until the end of stream, you can use `while(cin >> X)`.