# Why does this cause in infinite loop with chars but not doubles?

Tags: c++, loops

I feel like im doing something really silly wrong. I just want the program to  tell the user when they are entering non-doubles, and continue to loop back to the cin where you enter a value.

I want the user to input any number. Then essential do this trivial math and repeat. Its working fine in that regard, the problem comes when some unexpected input like a char gets entered. Then the input somehow sends it into a loop where it loops the math problem, instead of just telling the user that they must type a number and looping back to cin type in a new number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;

long double domath(long double i)
{ 
     cout << i << "/" << 2 << "=" << i/2 << endl;    
     cout << i/2 << "*" << 10 << "=" << (i/2)*10 << endl << endl;   
     cout << 5 << "*" << i << "=" << 5*i << "\n\n";      
     return 0;
}

int main()
{

    long double in = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        cin >> in;         
        if (cin.fail()) {             
            in = char(int(in));  
        }           
        domath(in);
    }
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample input, expected and actual output.

Comment: Please remove [tag:c] tag.

Comment: You need to clear cin, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928865/correct-way-to-use-cin-fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't clear the `cin` in case of fail, and it infinitely tries to parse wrong input to double, failing every time. You need to clear the buffer in case of error:

```
if (cin.fail()) {
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    in = char(int(in));
}
```

Also, can't understand what you're trying to achieve with

```
in = char(int(in));
```

`in` is a long double variable and will hold the last value you assigned to it, no need to "convert" it to do math.

Comment: Why don't I have to clear it with a numerical input?

Comment: @x4kepa because it successfully consumes it when parsing

Comment: Where do you learn stuff like this? Where does the specific knowledge of when to do stuff like this come from?

Comment: @x4kepa trial and error mostly, with heavy debugger and google usage

Comment: @x4kepa it is primarily practice and then the experience

Comment: @x4kepa did it help? If it did, upvoting and accepting an answer is a stackoverflow way to say thanks

Comment: By the way I was using `in = char(int(in));` to see if I could convert the char value into a number value so that it might pass right through as a number.

Comment: `in` is long double value, it's not a char, and doesn't store any chars from cin. If cin could convert the input into number, it would and store it in `in` variable

Comment: It says 'numeric_limits' & 'streamsize' undeclared.

Comment: @x4kepa add `std` namespace, I've modified the answer

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful, ive got to learn how to use the debugger on Dev, or learn how to not suck at coding..

Comment: _"Why don't I have to clear it with a numerical input?"_ You do. You just never had it set, so you didn't notice. You don't learn that through specific knowledge, but by thinking your solution through. :)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you try doing something like this?

```
int x;

if(std::cin >> x)
  doSomethingCool(x);
else
  std::cout << "Error, not a valid integer!" << std::endl;
```

Exit your loop on bad input.

I think this just feels more natural/looks cleaner than clearing the buffer and all the other jazz. Just my opinion.

[if (cin >> x) - Why can you use that condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791520/if-cin-x-why-can-you-use-that-condition)

edit: Bul's answer is still a good one though.