# When can I use explicit operator bool without a cast?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

My class has an explicit conversion to bool:

```
struct T {
    explicit operator bool() const { return true; }
};
```

and I have an instance of it:

```
T t;
```

To assign it to a variable of type `bool`, I need to write a cast:

```
bool b = static_cast<bool>(t);
bool b = bool(t);
bool b(t);  // converting initialiser
bool b{static_cast<bool>(t)};
```

I know that I can use my type directly in a conditional without a cast, despite the `explicit` qualifier:

```
if (t)
    /* statement */;
```

Where else can I use `t` as a `bool` without a cast?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The standard mentions places where a value may be *"**contextually converted to `bool`**"*.  They fall into four main groups:

### Statements

- ```
     if (t) /* statement */;
  ```
- ```
     for (;t;) /* statement */;
  ```
- ```
     while (t) /* statement */;
  ```
- ```
     do { /* block */ } while (t);
  ```

### Expressions

- ```
     !t
  ```
- ```
     t && t2
  ```
- ```
     t || t2
  ```
- ```
     t ? "true" : "false"
  ```

### Compile-time tests

- ```
     static_assert(t);
  ```
- ```
     noexcept(t)
  ```
- ```
     explicit(t)
  ```
- ```
     if constexpr (t)
  ```

The conversion operator needs to be `constexpr` for these.  From C++26 onwards, *narrowing* conversions (e.g. from integers other than 0 and 1) [are not permitted](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1401r5.html) in compile-time tests.

### Algorithms and concepts

- ```
     NullablePointer T
  ```

  Anywhere the Standard requires a type satisfying this concept (e.g. the `pointer` type of a `std::unique_ptr`), it may be contextually converted.  Also, the return value of a `NullablePointer`'s equality and inequality operators must be contextually convertible to `bool`.
- ```
     std::remove_if(first, last, [&](auto){ return t; });
  ```

  In any algorithm with a template parameter called `Predicate` or `BinaryPredicate`, the predicate argument can return a `T`.
- ```
     std::sort(first, last, [&](auto){ return t; });
  ```

  In any algorithm with a template parameter called `Compare`, the comparator argument can return a `T`.

([source1](https://chris-sharpe.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/contextually-converted-to-bool.html), [source2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions))

---

Do be aware that a mix of const and non-const conversion operators can cause confusion:

- [Why doesn't explicit bool() conversion happen in contextual conversion?](/q/22064519)
- [Why does the `explicit operator bool` not in effect as expected?](/q/24489762)