# explicit specifier doesn't seem to work when converting an object to bool

Tags: c++, type-conversion, explicit

I am learning C++ recently and I noticed an [example on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit), part of which goes like this:

```
struct B
{
    explicit B(int) { }
    explicit operator bool() const { return true; }
};

int main()
{
    B b2(2);       // OK: direct-initialization selects B::B(int)
    if (b2) ;      // OK: B::operator bool()
}
```

The introduction to [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) tells me "when the expression is used in an if statement or a loop" the result of this expression( b2 ) will be converted into `bool` type implicitly.

Also, the introduction to [explicit specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) tells me if "a conversion function is explicit, it cannot be used for implicit conversions".

Since b2 will be converted implicitly in `if(b2)`, and the conversion function is `explicit`, how comes `if(b2)` is ok?

Comment: Maybe reated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995573/when-can-i-use-explicit-operator-bool-without-a-cast

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Contextual conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions) is special; since C++11, `explicit` conversion functions will be considered in contextual conversions.

(emphasis mine)

> (since C++11)
>
> In the following contexts, the type `bool` is expected and **the implicit conversion is performed if the declaration `bool t(e);` is well-formed (that is, an explicit conversion function such as explicit T::operator bool() const; is considered)**. Such expression e is said to be ***contextually converted to bool***.
>
> - the controlling expression of if, while, for;
> - the operands of the built-in logical operators !, && and ||;
> - the first operand of the conditional operator ?:;
> - the predicate in a static_assert declaration;
> - the expression in a noexcept specifier;
> - the expression in an explicit specifier; (since C++20)
> - the predicate of a contract attribute. (since C++20)

That means for `if (b2)`, `b2` will be converted to `bool` implicitly by `B::operator bool()` even it's declared as `explicit`.

Answer (score 7):

Read [further in your own link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions). Contextual conversions occur implicitly even for `explicit` conversions:

> ### Contextual conversions
>
> In the following contexts, the type `bool` is expected and the implicit conversion is performed if the declaration `bool t(e)`; is well-formed (that is, an explicit conversion function such as `explicit T::operator bool() const;` is considered). Such expression `e` is said to be *contextually converted to `bool`*.
>
> - the controlling expression of `if`, `while`, `for`;
> - the operands of the built-in logical operators `!`, `&&` and `||`;
> - the first operand of the conditional operator `?:`;
> - the predicate in a `static_assert` declaration;
> - the expression in a `noexcept` specifier;
> - the expression in an `explicit` specifier;
> - the predicate of a contract attribute.