# Why can std::cin not be implicitly converted to bool?

Tags: c++, conversion-operator

In *C++ Primer 5th Ed.*, Chapter 14 discusses conversion operators:

> Under earlier versions of the standard, classes that wanted to define a conversion to bool faced a problem: Because bool is an arithmetic type, a class-type object that is converted to bool can be used in any context where an arithmetic type is expected.
>
> Such conversions can happen in surprising ways. In particular, if istream had a conversion to bool, the following code would compile:
>
> ```
> int i = 42;
> cin << i; // this code would be legal if the conversion to bool were not explicit!
> ```
>
> This program attempts to use the output operator on an input stream. There is no `<<` defined for `istream`, so the code is almost surely in error. However, this code could use the bool conversion operator to convert `cin` to `bool`. The resulting bool value would then be promoted to int and used as the left-hand operand to the built-in version of the left-shift operator. The promoted bool value (either 1 or 0) would be shifted left 42 positions.

Input streams can be converted to bool values representing the internal status of the stream (success or failure). We used to do:

```
while(std::cin >> str)...
```

So why shouldn't this compile?

```
int x = 0;
std::cin << x;
```

If I use an explicit cast it works:

```
(bool)cin << 5; // works although bad
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995573/when-can-i-use-explicit-operator-bool-without-a-cast

Comment: your line of reasoning is almost correct. The only detail you miss is that `if (std::cin >> x)` is allowed even though the conversion is declared as explicit as explained in the Q&A I linked above

Comment: This is why in the early days the conversion was not too bool. It was to a type that could be interrupted in a bool context (not exact words). As a result we used to return pointers to member functions. These could be null or a pointer and when placed in a bool context with true or false. i.e. like `while (cin >> val)` would return a stream that would then result in a conversion to a pointer like object which is an integer type so can be use to force the loop to exit. The old days were fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `operator bool` [is declared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) `explicit`, so it shouldn't be implicitly converted to a boolean:

```cpp
bool b = std::cin; // Error
```

So you need to explicitly convert `cin` to a boolean for it to work:

```cpp
bool b {std::cin}; // OK, explicitly converting
```

So when you try to call

```cpp
std::cin << 5;
```

It won't compile because you're expecting an implicit conversion, while the class only allows explicit ones. Which is this works:

```cpp
bool(std::cin) << 5;
```

Now, why does `while(std::cin >> x)` compile? The Standard guarantees an explicit conversion to `bool` in this situation. See the [great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995573/when-can-i-use-explicit-operator-bool-without-a-cast) linked in the question comments about that.