# What purpose to use "!!" inside the if statement

Tags: c++

I saw the code below recently:

```
std::error_code ec;

// --- some code

if (!!ec)
{
//error reaction
}
```

For what purpose the `!!` is used?
The only idea is to force bool operator, but for what?
May it have sense for some implementations of boost error types?

Comment: No, not you shouldn't use this not.

Comment: Code obfuscation merely.

Comment: you can convert an integer to `0` or `1` by `!!`, but in a context where anyhow a `bool` is expected I see no reason for it. Where did you see it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've done exactly this to quench a compiler warning.

Comment: @mark Fair point.

Comment: My guess is that some doofus had the same misguided idea as I did when I posted my (wrong) answer stating that implicit conversion to bool in an if statement is not possible. Admittedly this is not such a common thing in most C++ code I've read so maybe it's also just for clarity.

Comment: @idclev, I saw it in the code of tcp server based on boost asio. I have no possibility to share the code...

Comment: It's a common pattern in JavaScript to convert a variable to a bool.  It's largely unnecessary in C++, and fairly uncommon to see in C++.  (Likewise with C.)

Comment: @Peter, possibly your guess about `explicit` is correct. For `if()` it is not required, but may have sense in other cases...

Answer (score 1):

The use of `!!` inside `if` statement is redundant, as inside an `if` a value may be *contextually converted to bool* even if the casting is marked as `explicit`.

However, in an assignment this trick may be a substitute for an explicit cast:

```
std::error_code ec;

// some code

// bool is_error = ec;   // compilation error, operator bool is explicit
bool is_error1 = !!ec;   // ok
bool is_error2 = (bool)ec; // better, one may argue
bool is_error3 = static_cast<bool>(ec); // to avoid C-style cast
bool is_error4 = ec.value() != 0; // most verbose, also possible
```

It might be that the `if(!!ec)` is a copy-paste from an assignment expression.

See also: [When can I use explicit operator bool without a cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995573/when-can-i-use-explicit-operator-bool-without-a-cast)

---

A side note: there might be of course a case where this trick is relevant inside `if` - in case a type implements `operator!` and lacks `operator bool` - but this is not the case with `std::error_code`.

Comment: and C++ cast `static_cast<bool>(ec)` to avoid C-cast ;)

Comment: @Jarod42 added, for completeness

Answer (score 0):

It is a double negative. example:

```
int main()
{
    bool varTrue = true;
    std::cout << "varTrue = " << varTrue << std::endl;
    std::cout << "!varTrue = " << !varTrue << std::endl;
    std::cout << "!!varTrue = " << !!varTrue << std::endl;

}
```

Output

```
varTrue = 1
!varTrue = 0
!!varTrue = 1
```

It seems useless

Comment: Its about `std::error_code`... Possibly it may be used like this : `auto b = !!ec;`...

Comment: nobody said `varTrue` was a `bool`.  In fact, it is a `std::error_code` in the question.