# no suitable conversion function from (C++) std::istream &std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> to bool

Tags: c++

I've tried the types string and char with no success.

First post sorry if I did anything incorrectly.

[image]

```
if (inputFile.is_open())
{
    bool data = getline(inputFile, line, '$');
    while (data)
    {
        name = line;
        getline(inputFile, course, '$');
        getline(inputFile, line, '$');
        clearGrading = line == "1" ? true : false;
        getline(inputFile, line, '$');
        goodFeedback = line == "1" ? true : false;
        getline(inputFile, line, '$');
        caring = line == "1" ? true : false;
        getline(inputFile, line, '$');
        reachable = line == "1" ? true : false;
        getline(inputFile, line, '$');
        toughGrader = line == "1" ? true : false;
        getline(inputFile, line, '$');
        lectureHeavy = line == "1" ? true : false;
        getline(inputFile, line, '$');
        attendance = line == "1" ? true : false;
        data = getline(inputFile, line, '$');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your code as text, not images.  For people that can't see images for one reason or another your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not an image of your IDE.

Comment: image of program when run https://imgur.com/gallery/zCIATHj and File being read https://imgur.com/gallery/FAxrbtb

Comment: Don't write code like this: `clearGrading = line == "1" ? true : false;`.  Just say: `clearGrading = (line == "1");`

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
bool data = getline(inputFile, line, '$');
while (data)
{
```

The return value of `getline()` is not a `bool`, it's the original input stream (the first param to `getline()`) - likely such chaining can be done or so that it can be invoked in a loop

Easy fix is simply this:

```
while (getline(inputFile, line, '$'))
{
```

Two other issues.  Don't have code that explicitly converts a boolean expression to true/false. Just let the boolean expression be itself.

Instead of this:

```
caring = line == "1" ? true : false;
```

This:

```
caring = (line == "1");
```

Finally, I would recommend you check the stream state after every call to `getline()`.  You aren't doing that consistently.  That is, instead of this:

```
name = line;
getline(inputFile, course, '$');
getline(inputFile, line, '$');
```

Do this:

```
name = line;
if (inputfile)
    getline(inputFile, course, '$');
if (inputfile)
    getline(inputFile, line, '$');
```

Comment: _"or so that it can be invoked in a loop"_ Yeah, via conversion to bool...

Answer (score 0):

`std::getline()` returns a reference to the input `istream` it is given.  The stream has a [`bool` conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) defined to test the stream state in a boolean context.  However, since C++11, that operator is marked as `explicit`, which means it can't be used to initialize a `bool` variable without an explicit type-cast, eg:

```cpp
bool data = (bool) getline(inputFile, line, '$');
```

Or:

```cpp
bool data = static_cast<bool>(getline(inputFile, line, '$'));
```

However, `explicit` operators are allowed to be used without type-cast in certain contexts, which includes `while` statements (see [When can I use explicit operator bool without a cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995573/)), eg:

```cpp
while (getline(inputFile, line, '$'))
```