# how boolean_type operator is getting called on if statment?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a header file that defines a class with a `boolean_type` conversion operator in it, which is used in `main.cpp`. I am not able to understand how the `boolean_type` operator is getting called in an `if` statement

Header.h

```
template <typename Type>
class Sptr
{
public:
    struct boolean_struct { int member; };
    typedef int boolean_struct::* boolean_type;

    operator boolean_type() const throw()
    {
        return nullptr != m_value ? &boolean_struct::member : nullptr;
    }

    explicit Sptr(Type value = nullptr) throw() :
        m_value(value)
    {
    }

private:
    Type m_value;
};
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    int* p = new int;
    Sptr<int*> sPtr(p);
    if (sPtr) //>>>>> How this is calling operator boolean_type() ?
    {
        std::cout << "hellos";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is all to happy to make a construct work, so long as it can (within certain constraints) find a valid conversion sequence to types that work in the given context.

In this case, the compiler sees an `if` statement, which expects an operator of type `bool`. It will therefore attempt to form a `bool` value from `sPtr`. A conversion sequence can be formed from at most one user-defined conversion, but may contain more standard conversions.

In this case, the first conversion in the sequence is the user defined one to `boolean_type`. Following that, we can perform the following standard conversion

> **[conv.bool]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/conv.bool#1) A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or **pointer-to-member type** can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`. A zero value, null pointer value, or **null member pointer value** is converted to `false`; any other value is converted to `true`.

`boolean_type` is a [pointer-to-member type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/pointer-to-class-data-member). And so can be converted to the `bool` we need for the `if` statement to work.

The reason such code may have been written in the past, is in the first paragraph to this answer. C++ can be too conversion happy. Had the user-defined conversion been a plain `operator bool`, one could end up with silliness such as this

```
sPtr * 2; // What is multiplying a pointer even mean!? Why?
foo(sPtr); // But foo expects an int!
```

The conversion to `bool` permits using `sPtr` in contexts that require an integral type, because, as it were, `bool` is also an integral type in the C++ type system! We don't want that. So the above trick is employed to prevent the compiler from considering our user-defined conversion in more contexts than we want.

Nowadays, such tricks are not required. Since C++11, we have the notion of type being [contextually converted and `explicit` conversion operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995573/when-can-i-use-explicit-operator-bool-without-a-cast). Basically if we write instead

```
explicit operator bool()
```

This operator will only be called in very specific contexts (such as the condition in an `if` statement), but not implicitly in the problematic examples listed above.