# Why isn't shared_ptr implicitly converted to boolean when returning it in a function?

Tags: c++, boolean, shared-ptr, implicit-conversion, return-type

The following won't compile:

```
#include <memory>
class A;
bool f() {
    std::shared_ptr<A> a;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

and fails with:

```
Compilation failed due to following error(s).main.cpp: In function ‘bool f()’:
main.cpp:13:12: error: cannot convert ‘std::shared_ptr’ to ‘bool’ in return
     return a;
```

What could be the reasoning of the standard (I presume) not allowing an implicit conversion here?

Comment: Probably the safe bool problem: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#The_safe_bool_problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the [user-defined operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_bool) for converting an `std::shared_ptr` to `bool` is **explicit**:

```
explicit operator bool() const noexcept;
```

---

Note that an implicit conversion to `bool` in the condition of an `if` statement – [among others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39995574/8012646) – still happens even with an *explicit* user-defined conversion operator to `bool` :

```
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr;

if (ptr) { // <-- implicit conversion to bool

}
```

That is, you don't need to write `static_cast<bool>(ptr)` in the condition of an `if` statement.