# Template class: operator []: 2 overloads have similar conversions

Tags: c++, json, templates

I built a simple JSON encoder/decoder in C++ (I know there are many excellent solutions for this problem out there; I'm learning the language, and it's simply a challenge to myself, and I'm not about to pretend that my solution is any good).

Initially, I had the following two `operator []` overloads:

```cpp
json& operator[](const std::string& key) {
  assert_type_valid(/* "object" type */);
  return (*object_data_)[key];
}

json& operator[](size_t index) {
  assert_type_valid(/* "array" type */);
  return (*array_data_)[index];
}

...

std::unique_ptr<std::unordered_map<std::string, json>> object_data_;
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<json>> array_data_;
```

And this worked great! I could do something like `my_json["someKey"]["someOtherKey"][4]["thirdKey"]` to access nested values.

But then, because my project uses a bunch of Windows APIs that make use of both `char`/`std::string` and `wchar_t`/`std::wstring`, I wanted to make both `json` and `wjson` types, so I turned my existing `json` class and parser into a `basic_json<CharType, StringType>`.

Now, the same code looks like:

```cpp
// Using C for CharType and S for StringType for brevity here...

basic_json<C, S>& operator[](const S& key) {
  assert_type_valid(/* "object" type */);
  return (*object_data_)[key];
}

basic_json<C, S>& operator[](size_t index) {
  assert_type_valid(/* "array" type */);
  return (*array_data_)[index];
}

...

std::unique_ptr<std::unordered_map<S, basic_json<C, S>>> object_data_;
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<basic_json<C, S>>> array_data_;
```

Attempting to use either `operator []` now results in this error:

```
error C2666: 'basic_json<char,std::string>::operator []': 2 overloads have similar conversions

could be ...::operator [](size_t)
or       ...::operator [](const S &)
or       built-in C++ operator[(__int64, const char [8])
```

I've tried adding a third `operator [](const C* key)` overload, but that hasn't made a difference.

**My actual question**: Why has templating caused this?

I'm under the impression that template types are determined at compile time, so presumably the compiler should understand what `C` and `S` are and be able to know that I'm not passing in a `size_t` when I do `my_json["someKey"]`.

Also, I feel like templating has turned the once-pretty code into a huge mess. Is it ever worth simply duplicating a bunch of code in a situation like this? Like having a second parser that just works explicitly with `wchar_t` and `std::wstring`?

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Why not just use an `auto` return type?

Comment: ...I was unaware that `auto` could be used as a class member function return type. I assumed the signatures always had to be explicitly defined, for whatever reason.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the member variables in `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1add73a3480bf9b1). Do you have any implicit conversions defined? Implicit conversions are Evil.

Comment: @molbdnilo It was an implicit conversion after all (see accepted answer). I'm not well versed in parsing C++ error messages yet, so I didn't think it was relevant. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Why has templating caused this?"*
Because class template members are only instantiated when necessary.

The clue appears to be in the operator[] which you did not mention:

`built-in C++ operator[(__int64, const char [8])`.

That is to say, the compiler considers `5["someKey"]`. Wait, what? Yes, in C++ that is valid. It's the same as `"someKey"[5]`, for compatibility with C.

Now how is that even relevant? Your `basic_json<C, S>` has an implicit conversion to `int` and `std::string` has an implicit conversion from `const char [8]`, so the two overloads are equal.

The fix: remove the implicit conversion to `int`.

Comment: Oh my God, it's because I also added an `operator bool()` at some point during the switch from non-template to template, which I didn't mention because I didn't think it was relevant at all. I'm assuming that, because `bool` is convertible to `int`, that makes the whole class implicitly convertible to `int` as well? Would be really, really nice if the error message made that remotely clear...just one more thing you get used to over time, I suppose.

Comment: @Dave: And that's not `explicit`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995573/when-can-i-use-explicit-operator-bool-without-a-cast

Comment: No, it was not marked `explicit`.