# Under exactly what conditions does (stringstream >> integer) fail and succeed? C++

Tags: c++, converters, stringstream

So I'm trying to understand how exactly the truth value of (stringstream >> int variable) works. Let the code be something like this:

```
int number;
stringstream convert("string");
if (convert >> number) {do something;}
```

Could someone please explain to me *when exactly* does (convert >> number) evaluate to true and when to false, since it is not identical to successful initialisation of an integer variable. For clarification, I know *why* it works, it works because it evaluates to a `bool`. The question is *how* exactly does it work. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791520/if-cin-x-why-can-you-use-that-condition) question does not deal with the same problem.

I've seen similar questions, but they don't address exactly this problem. During testing I found some ways in which it's different from normal initialization of an int variable. For example:

```
int number = 2147483648;
```

causes an overflow, but the assignment is successful nonetheless. On the other hand

```
int number;
stringstream convert("2147483648");
(convert >> number)
```

evaluates to false. It is not identical to the "correct" initialisation either. For example

```
unsigned int number;
stringstream convert("2147483648");
(convert >> number)
```

evaluates to `true`, as expected, but

```
unsigned int number;
stringstream convert("-1");
(convert >> number)
```

evaluates to true also, even though `unsigned int` expects a positive value.

What else is different? Thank you.

Comment: This provides detailed info: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt