# Stroustrup Ex.7, Chap.4 - C++ Syntax

Tags: c++, function

I'm new to C++ and, as many others here, I'm trying to learn it from Bjarne Stroustrup's Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++.

I'm stuck on Exercise 7, Chap.4., where the idea is to write a calculator that, when the input is either **an integer and/or a string** followed by a **character (+,-,* or /)**, the output should announce **"the sum/diff/prod/ratio of"** input **1** and input **2** is the result; so if ("**two**" **3** *) is the input, the output should be **"the product of 2 * 3 = 6"**.

Here's Stroustrup's solution (I'm leaving Stroustrup's comments):

-- There's no copyright infringement, as this is all from his website --

```
 /*The solution uses two functions (in addition to main():
        initialize_numbers() to initialize the vector of number string 
        representations
        get_number() to read a number that is either a string or a sequence of 
        digits
    */

vector<string> numbers; // representation of numbers as strings
                        // numbers[i] is the string representation for i
                        // for numbers[0] to numbers[numbers.size()-1]

void initialize_numbers()
{
    numbers.push_back("zero");
    numbers.push_back("one");
    numbers.push_back("two");
    numbers.push_back("three");
    numbers.push_back("four");
    numbers.push_back("five");
    numbers.push_back("six");
    numbers.push_back("seven");
    numbers.push_back("eight");
    numbers.push_back("nine");
    numbers.push_back("ten");   // why not? :-)
}

int get_number()
{
    const int not_a_symbol = numbers.size();    // not_a_symbol is a value that does not correspond
                                                // to a string in the numbers vector
    int val = not_a_symbol;
    if (cin>>val) return val; // try to read an integer composed of digits

    cin.clear();    // clear string after failed attempt to read an integer
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    for (int i=0; i<numbers.size(); ++i)    // see if the string is in numbers
        if (numbers[i]==s) val = i;
    if (val==not_a_symbol) error("unexpected number string: ",s);
    return val;
}

int main()
try
{ initialize_numbers();

cout<< "please enter two floating-point values separated by an operator\n The operator can be + - * / % : ";

while (true) {  // "forever"; that is until we give an unacceptable input or make a computations error
    int val1 = get_number();

    char op = 0;
    cin>>op; // get the operator

    int val2 = get_number();

    string oper;    // text appropriate for an operator
    double result;

    switch (op) {
    case '+':
        oper = "sum of ";
        result = val1+val2; 
        break;
    case '-':
        oper = "difference between ";
        result = val1-val2; 
        break;
    case '*':
        oper = "product of ";
        result = val1*val2; 
        break;
    case '/':
        oper = "ratio of ";
        if (val2==0) error("trying to divide by zero");
        result = val1/val2; 
        break;
    case '%':
        oper = "remainder of ";
        if (val2==0) error("trying to divide by zero (%)");
        result = val1%val2; 
        break;
    default:
            error("bad operator");
    }
    cout << oper << val1 << " and " << val2 << " is " << result << '\n';
    cout << "Try again: ";
}
```

}

More specifically, my problem is with the following part:

```
 int get_number()
    {
        const int not_a_symbol = numbers.size();    // not_a_symbol is a value that does not correspond
                                                    // to a string in the numbers vector
        int val = not_a_symbol;
        if (cin>>val) return val; // try to read an integer composed of digits

        cin.clear();    // clear string after failed attempt to read an integer
```

etc etc etc...
        }

I just don't understand what's going on here, in the big context. I'm having trouble understanding this whole get_number() function, and how it relates to the rest of the code.

1 - Why assign the value of **number.size()** to **not_a_symbol**? What does this  accomplish?

2 - **if (cin >> val)** - why is that the conditional? val is == size of vector numbers, which is 11, so is the conditional the number 11? How is that helpful?
And what is it returning? Itself?

3 - **// try to read an integer composed of digits** - how is that accomplished, and why is that helpful?

Thank you, and sorry for the long format of the question.

Comment: `numbers.size()` is one more than the last number, as the indexing starts at 0. That's all it is - not one of the numbers in the vector.

Comment: But the vector has strings, and there are 11 elements (zero to ten) and function numbers.size() returns number of elements inside the vector. I don't know what you mean.

Comment: For `if (cin >> val)`, the conditional is the return value of `std::cin.operator bool()`.  Long story short, streaming operators (operators `<<` and `>>`, when used on a stream) return the left-hand argument (e.g., `cin >> val` returns `cin`, and `cout << x` returns `cout`), so they can be chained together (e.g., because `cout << x` returns `cout`, `cout << x << y` is valid, and becomes `(cout << x) << y`, or `cout << x; cout << y`).  `if` accepts an expression that can be converted to `bool`.

Comment: Thus, `if (cin >> val)` is effectively `cin >> val; if (cin)`, which means that `cin` is converted to `bool`, which uses conversion operator `std::istream::operator bool()`.  This operator returns the stream's state.  So, finally, `if (cin >> val)` reads `val` from `cin`, then checks whether `cin` is still in a valid state.  It's basically "Did we break anything?  No?  Good."

Comment: @JustinTime Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You're welcome.  It's useful to know how that works, because attempting to read inside a conditional check guarantees that the operations which depend on that read will only be executed if the read was successful (an unsuccessful read puts an `istream` into an invalid state, which `operator bool()` translates to `false`, thus preventing the code which relied on that read from executing).  [This is commonly used to determine whether the end of the file has been reached](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5605159/5386374), during file I/O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to take away your answer, man, but I figured it out by myself, and the thing is much more simple (and clever).

The for-loop works as it should, comparing input strings to the strings inside the vector and returning the correspondent index number.

But the reason to assign the value of numbers.size() to not_a_symbol, giving val the value of numbers.size() resides in the fact that, if the first IF fails, and only then, the second will become true, since val was already initialized. That's why there's 2 separated IF statements, instead of an IF-ELSE: an ELSE would not make the previously initialized val count, because the input from string "s" would take over, preventing val's initial value to work on (val=not_a_symbol) inside the ELSE.

Forget the functions, put it all inside the main:

```
int main() {

    vector<string> numbers{ "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten" };
    int not = numbers.size();
    int val = numbers.size(); //val is initialized
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    for (int i = 0; i<numbers.size(); ++i)
        if (numbers[i] == s) val = i; // first IF; if this condition is not met, it will return val as it was initialized (val=numbers.size() or 11) 
    if (val == not) val = 88; // then this condition will be checked. It will be true. It will return val = 88 (a random number);

    cout << "val is: " << val << "\n" << "not is: " << not << "\n";
}
```

So, it's not a matter of comparing val with the vector's number of elements, is a matter of val already being equal to it and that fact acting upon the failing of the first condition.

Answer (score 2):

1. In `for` that is in whole function `get_number()` `i` goes from 0 to one less than `numbers.size()` and puts `i` where input string not containing digits compared with one of strings in `numbers` vector into `val`(so you convert name of number into value of number). After that you check if `val` is same as size of vector `numbers` because if it is, there was no match(someone entered word that is not name of any number you can handle).
2. From [if (cin >> x) - Why can you use that condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791520/if-cin-x-why-can-you-use-that-condition) `cin>>val`(cin reads from input into variable val) will return false if you enetred atleast one letter.
3. If you enter number with no letters you can return it (we want either string representing name of number or a normal digit).

Comment: Thank you. That helps a lot.

Comment: I've read the link you had provided. It's very informative. Unfortunately, the book gets ahead of itself a lot, which, if it's good because it forces us to go after answers, it's also time-consuming in a, sometimes, almost  absurd way: I had no way of guessing about classes, inheritance and operator overloading. Thank you very much for your interesting on my question. Choosing your answer not only because it's the only one, but because it really helped me.